# Remap escape key for entering special characters?

Tags: keyboard

My keyboard does not have an escape key, and remapping it through my computer/keyboard settings is turning out to be much harder than I previously thought. Also, `Ctrl+[` does not work for me.

Therefore, I'm wondering if it's possible to change the definition of the key to enter special characters could be mapped to a different key. Is this possible?

I checked Edit->Preferences but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Also, in some Apple Macbook Pro models, there is no escape key.

Comment: @QuantumDot As well as [this prototype](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BGGOn-H7s3Q)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quit Mathematica. Look up the file `KeyEventTranslations.tr` in your installation directory. Open it in any editor (but better *not* in the Mathematica editor). Find the line

```
Item[KeyEvent["Escape"], "ShortNameDelimiter"]
```

and change `KeyEvent["Escape"]` to whatever you want, e.g. to `KeyEvent["a", Modifiers -> {Shift, Control}]` for <kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. Changes take effect when you start Mathematica FrontEnd the next time.

Search also for "KeyEventTranslations.tr" on this site for many other useful ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for asking the question. I have the same problem now that I have a new MacBook Pro (13") with the "Touchbar" with software defined keys, but no escape key while in the Mathematica app.
In MacOS Preferences -> Keyboard I selected "Touchbar Shows... Expanded Keyboard" so that when I hit the "fn" key, the escape key shows in the Touchbar.