# Enter special character in search box

Tags: front-end, searching, dialog-window

Usually, I just enter special characters with the `Esc` key and hence am not familiar with their real code in plain text. But this seems troublesome in the search box opened by `Ctrl+F` since `Esc` simply quits the box. Although some plain text `\[Omega]` seems to work, I was wondering if any other workaround that more or less allows me to stick to the usual habit. [Mapping](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175331) `Esc` to some other key looks a bit overkilling, any other mild solution?

Comment: As a easier workflow, try copy the text from somewhere else. To rebind the keys, see `KeyEventTranslations.tr`, which you can learn something about from this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typing this in the little search box (as it is shown) finds ESC characters in notebook:

```
 \[AliasDelimiter]
```

In the search box. This will find an ESC entered in the notebook.

Here is a movie

[image]

Reference [AliasDelimiter](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/AliasDelimiter.html)

[image]

This page [ListingOfNamedCharacters](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfNamedCharacters.html)  Gives the names of all characters known to Mathematica including special ones.

Comment: Thanks. This is indeed a valid solution. If only the delimiter could be typed more easily. Maybe too wishful... Let's see if no other answer, I will accept this.

Answer (score 0):

I complained after upgrading to vs 13 that Esc .. Esc for input of special character  is still closing the Find&Replace box.

I have forgotten about the answer, searching this site produced the answer her, but Wolframs answer was shorter, a key combination.

After three attempts:

Enclose text in "Shift+Esc" :-)  "Shift+Esc"

( emoji copy table working with "Windows" + "[" + "." )